# How to release memory when using Win32 dll?

Tags: c#, memory, dll

```
dllManager.LoadFun(@"user32", "GetAsyncKeyState");
object tempFlag = dllManager.Invoke(ObjArray_Parameter, TypeArray_ParameterType, ModePassArray_Parameter, Type_Return, "GetAsyncKeyState");
r = (int)tempFlag;
llManager.UnLoadDll(); 

public void UnLoadDll()
{
    FreeLibrary(hModule);
    hModule = IntPtr.Zero;
    farProc = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

`dllManager.UnloadDll()` does not seem to work, the memory is not released as when I call the DLL once again, it will continue to increase the memory. How do I release the memory?

Comment: did you try `GC.Collect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you declare an `extern` function, and don't worry too much about memory usage.  Windows uses this DLL internally anyway.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    short state = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.D);
    switch (state)
    {
        // ?
    }
}
```

**See also**
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate

Answer (score 0):

You can load that link library inside an [Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and then unload that application domain.

Comment: Wrong. He's talking about native DLLs.

Comment: @SLaks By native, do you mean Win32?